# Can not import image in javascript . Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

this error is occuring in my react application.

the full message says
./bluecardback.jpg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

webpack.config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.join(__dirname, './src/index.js')
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'] } }],
    },
    { 
      test: /\.(less|css|scss)$/, 
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader',] 
    }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    // historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    })
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dnd": "^14.0.3",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "less": "^3.10.3",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development --port=4000 --inline --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  }
}
```

my import looks like this `import background from "../bluecardback.jpg";`

Comment: `import` [is for importing components](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/), which is code.  You cannot import a `.jpg` file.  You're importing "background" from a jpg file; how is it possible to even define a background function in a JPG file?

Comment: i use the import like this in my component as attribute
<div style={{backgroundImage :`url(${background})`,}}></div>

Answer (score 5):

Your config is missing a [loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) for jpg file.

Try adding this

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
  loader: 'file-loader'
}
```

to your `module.rules` array in `webpack.config`.

Comment: This solution works, but you have to install the file-loader package first. Run `npm install --save-dev file-loader`and then add the code

Comment: Thank for this solution! Amazing webpack just doesn't put this in place, such a basic thing. There are many 'examples' on the interweb showing how to do file imports, but strangely they leave out this crucial step! Why can't they just go on Joe Rogan and waffle on about Himalayan salt crystals and how insulin is what's making your butt so fat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `const background = require('../bluecardback.jpg').default;`

or where you are using the jpg like

`<img src={require('../bluecardback.jpg').default} />`

Comment: unfortuntely the issue persists with this solution